# Postgres SQL mapping JSON blob to record when fields contain special PSQL operators (such as +, -)

Tags: json, postgresql

one of our DB tables has a JSON blob field containing keys with special PSQl operators such as "+", and "-". (E.g. "threshold-10", "threshold-5", "threshold+0" , "threshold+5")

For some reason the following query cannot seem to parse the json blobs correctly (returns empty for those specified fields) I've tried updating the query using quotation marks, but still having trouble using the jsonb_to_record function.

E.g

I've tried defining the schema without quotes but I get a syntax error at the minus and plus symbols.

```
SELECT * FROM jsonb_to_record(
       SELECT json_blob_column FROM my_table WHERE type = 'data_type'
) AS x (threshold-10 float, threshold-5, threshold+0, threshold+5)
```

I've also tried putting the fields in quotes to no avail: the syntax error disappears but then I'm left with a bunch of empty columns meaning these "threshold field" couldn't be found in the JSON blobs.

```
SELECT * FROM jsonb_to_record(
       SELECT json_blob_column FROM my_table WHERE type = 'data_type'
) AS x ("threshold-10" float, "threshold-5" float, "threshold+0" float, "threshold+5" float)
```

I'm now at loss. Really considering the JSON fields to "threshold_minus_5", "threshold_plus_five" to avoid the '+' and '-' symbols altogether.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add some sample data and desired output. As for as behavior concern its an obvious behavior because double quotes will allow `-` in field name but you are not providing and data to these fields in your subquery